# Constructing a jagged array in Java and hitting two contradictory errors

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

Hello I'm a noob programmer and I'm using BlueJ as my IDE.
This is my code to construct the array

```
public class letters
{
char[][] colors = new char[3][];
    colors[0] = new char[3];
    colors[1] = new char[9];
    colors[2] = new char[3];

public letters()
{

}

public char getCharacter(int x, int y)
{
    return this.colors[x][y];
}
```

}

The array is constructed outside of any methods in my class.
However, I keep on getting an error that says the compiler expects a ']' where the 0 is, but when I erase the 0, it complains that there is a "missing identifier."

So I was wondering, what does my compiler mean by a "missing identifier," and how do I make my jagged array work.

Comment: I'm guessing you're also assigning outside of any methods? e.g. `colors[0] = new char[3];`

Comment: Your code [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/1w2QkY)

Comment: yes, the declaration is outside of any methods.

Comment: would it be that BlueJ  complaining for no reason(it has done that before)

Comment: The code you've posted is OK.  You'll need to post more code for us to help you with an error.

Comment: "would it be that BlueJ complaining for no reason": Unless your configuration is entirely messed up, then no.  Try making a copy of your source, then whittling it down to as small a program as you can that still gives you the error.  Then post that.

Comment: Move the assignments inside a block (initializer, constructor, method, etc). Then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the declaration is outside of any methods.

There is only one declaration there - the first line. The three *assignments* are executable code, not declarations.

Assignments and other executable code is prohibited in the declaration portion of the class. All executable statements must be part of a method or an initializer, i.e.

```
char[][] colors = new char[3][];

{   // Initializer code
    colors[0] = new char[3];
    colors[1] = new char[9];
    colors[2] = new char[3];
}
```

Better yet, include initialization with the declaration itself:

```
char[][] colors = new char[][] {
    new char[3]
,   new char[9]
,   new char[3]
};
```

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight.